# Cosmos DB Attachment Limits and Alternate Attachment Locations

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We're moving the data storage for our core product to Cosmos DB. For documents, it works very well but I'm having trouble finding the information I need for attachments.

I can successfully do everything I want with attachments from my C# code using the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB NuGet ackage v 1.19.1.

According to information I can find, attachments are limited to 2GB total for all attachments in an account. This is hugely limiting. Info found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#attachments-and-media

It states:

> Azure Cosmos DB allows you to store binary blobs/media either with Azure Cosmos DB (maximum of 2 GB per account) or to your own remote media store.

There seems to be some implication that you can create attachments that point to resources stored elsewhere. Perhaps on a CDN. But I can't find any documentation how to actually do this from C#.

Does anyone know if Cosmos DB can, in fact, attach to BLOB payloads stored outside of itself? If so, can the .NET NuGet package do it or is it only available for pure REST calls?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently built-in to manage externally-stored attachments. Rather, it's up to you to store them and then reference them.

The most common pattern is to store a URL to the specific attachment, with a document (e.g. to a blob in Azure Storage). This results in effectively two operations:

- A query to retrieve the document from Cosmos DB
- A read from storage, based on the URL found in the returned Cosmos DB document.

Note: all responsibility is on you to manage referenced content: updating it, deleting it, etc. And if you're using blob storage, you'll need to deal with things such as private vs public access (and generating SAS for private URLs where necessary, when returning URLs to your clients, vs streaming content).

One more thing: CDN isn't a storage mechanism on its own. You cannot store something directly to CDN; that's more of a layer on top of something like Azure Storage (for public-accessible content).

Comment: David...One minor correction - attachments are stored separately from the document. Fetching the document will not bring the attachments. One would need a separate query to retrieve them.

Comment: @GauravMantri - Correct, and that's what (I thought) I stated. The scenario I described requires reading both a document (containing a url to some blob in storage) and then a retrieval of blob content (for streaming, or just passing the url).

Comment: Actually its a 3 step process - 1) Read the document 2) Find attachment(s) for that document and 3) Read contents from the URL stored in the attachment. If attachment is actually a property in the document, then indeed its a 2 step process.

Comment: @GauravMantri - I see the confusion now. I'm completely ignoring the Cosmos DB attached-document (as the OP already wants to move on from that, given the limitations). I'm merely describing the method of bypassing built-in attachments and using external blob storage.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the information. The thing I was trying to get at is whether I could use the Attachment mechanism in Cosmos DB to store a URL to media, rather than to store the media itself. The advantage here is that you can update media without changing the document itself.

If not, I would have to just make the attachments part of the document structure. Then, when I change attachments, the whole document updates. That's okay. Less desirable but okay.